# MS Access. How do I hide all text boxes in a report if one textbox data is blank

Tags: ms-access

Please help. I have a report with 5 text boxes. How do i hide all the other text boxes if one text box is empty or have no data in the corresponding table field.

Comment: Are you saying that if ANY of the 5 are empty, then hide all 5? Or only hide all 5 if #1 is empty? What are the field types involved?

Comment: Yes, i want to hide all the 5 if any of the text box is empty. Hiding all the text boxes if one box is empty  would also work for me. Any idea?

Comment: The report is representing data from a table with a column containg numbers and the rest are normal text.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the fields that the 5 text boxes are bound to? If any are text, do they allow empty string?

Comment: One box is bound to fields with numbers and the rest are bound to texts. Fields with text are allow to be empty but the fields with numbers are not allowed to be empty. My only challenge is to hide all tex boxes if one field is emty and only display them all if they all have data in them. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
If IsNull(Me!txtbox1.Value + Me!txtbox2.Value + Me!txtbox3.Value + Me!txtbox4.Value + Me!txtbox5.Value) Then
    Me!txtbox1.Visible = False
    Me!txtbox2.Visible = False
    Me!txtbox3.Visible = False
    Me!txtbox4.Visible = False
    Me!txtbox5.Visible = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between null and empty, which is why I asked about the text fields allowing empty string. I was trying to provide the simplest solution, but since you are not answering that question, here is what will work.
In the format event of the detail section (or whichever section the text boxes are located) place this code.

```
Dim binVis as Boolean
binVis = (IsNull(Me!YourNumberFieldTextBox) Or Nz(Me!YourTextBox1,"") = "" Or Nz(Me!YourTextBox2,"") = "" Or Nz(Me!YourTextBox3,"") = "" Or Nz(Me!YourTextBox4,"") = "")
Me!YourNumberFieldTextBox.Visible = binVis
Me!YourTextBox1= binVis
Me!YourTextBox2= binVis
Me!YourTextBox3= binVis
Me!YourTextBox4= binVis
```